# Storing data in string and comparing

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to make a program which takes city name from user and store that in std::string data and if user input is equal one of the cities in data it will give error. The problem is I can't properly assign variable "last" in while loop. By the way, this is part of my homework. However I can't achieve what I want, when "while" first looped there is no problem but after first loop problems start to occur.

If better title you have in your mind, please inform :)

To be inform, I managed to handle everything in main homework, this is just demo so first letter of city name must be capital for this demo.

You can see below;

```
int main()
{
    string cityName;

    cout << "Hello, enter city name : " << endl;
    cin >> cityName;

    bool anySameCity=false;
    string data = "-Istanbul-Ankara-Izmir-Kayseri-";
    string last = "";
    int index = data.find("-");
    while(index != string::npos)
    {
        last = "";
        last = data.substr(index+1, data.find("-", index+1)-1);
        index = data.find("-", index+1);

        if(last == cityName)
        {
            anySameCity = true;
        }   
    }
    if( anySameCity == true)
    {
        data = data + cityName + "-";
        cout << "Added!" << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use std::set<std::string> to keep track of entered cities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need while loop here you can just search city in the string:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                 
#include <string>                                                                                   
using namespace std;                                                                                
int main()                                                                                          
{                                                                                                   
    string cityName;                                                                                

    cout << "Hello, enter city name : " << endl;                                                    
    cin >> cityName;                                                                                

    bool anySameCity=false;                                                                         
    string data = "-Istanbul-Ankara-Izmir-Kayseri-";                                                
    if(data.find("-" + cityName + "-") != string::npos)                                                         
    {                                                                                               
        anySameCity = true;                                                                         
    }                                                                                               
    // .......................                                                                      
    if( !anySameCity )                                                                        
    {                                                                                               
        data = data + cityName + "-";                                                               
        cout << "Added!" << endl;                                                                   
    }                                                                                               

}
```

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you very much. I guess I obsessed with one solution and can't see another one.

Comment: Surely `if ( anySameCity == true )` should be `if ( !anySameCity )`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson : Yes, you are right. But the way I tried, I can't even reach there as I ended up with strange results.

Answer (score 1):

You know there are cities with a hyphen? Use a different separator, i suggest `'\n'`.

If you begin and end your data with the separator, you can search for the string separator+city+separator to find out if it is already in the data.

Last, do not compare to true. Just use the variable directly.

Also, i think you want to invert the anySameCity check...

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'm implementing but what I can't figure out is "search for the string separator+city+separator to find out if it is already in the data" part.

Comment: Okey I understand what you meant there now :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
int valid(std::string a, std::string b){
int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length() ; i++)
    if(a[i] == b[0])
        for(int j = 1; j < b.length() ; j++)
            if(a[i +j] != b[j])
                x = 1;
return x;
```

}

You can use this function to check whether new city name taken from user is in the data or not. Furthermore you can use this function in while loop to operate accordingly.